# Extract data from QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTableView` instance limited to a single row selection. I don't want to care about what cell the user presses, but it should always extract the data in (selectedRow,0).

So far I am doing the following:

```
QModelIndexList indices = _ui->_tbl->selectionModel()->selection().indexes();
QModelIndex id = indices.at(0).sibling(indices.at(0).row(),0);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in Qt doc concerning `currentIndex` :

> Unless the current selection mode is NoSelection, the item is also be
>   selected

So you can do it quicker :

```
QModelIndex index = _ui->_tbl->currentIndex() ;
QModelIndex id = index.sibling(index.row(),0) ;
```

Comment: I can't find it in the [doc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#currentIndex). Is there another doc I'm not aware of? =)

Comment: @Royi i found this sentence in Qt 4.7.3 doc `QAbstractItemView::setCurrentIndex()`

Answer (score 1):

Using `QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows` takes out one step. It gives you the index at a particular column (o by default). Thus:

```
QModelIndex index = _ui->_tbl->selectionModel()->selectedRows(0).at(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data of the first cell of the selected row, if you go through the `model`.

```
QModelIndex id = _ui->_tbl->model()->index(_ui->_tbl->currentIndex().row(),0);
```

Unfortunately `Qt` does not support (and I can't figure out why) a `QModelIndex` constructor with `row` and `column` as arguments.

Comment: I'd want a direct method to retrieve the elements from widgets such as tables, trees, lists, etc..