# Extract last column data from QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt

From the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328041/extract-data-from-qtableview), I found the way to access the first column of the selected row in QTableView. But how do i access the last column, without hardcoding the column number?

```
        itmIndex = self.viewInQuestion.currentIndex()
        id = itmIndex.sibling(itmIndex.row(), -1)
```

doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The below method worked:

```
        itmIndex = self.viewInQuestion.currentIndex()
        id = itmIndex.sibling(itmIndex.row(), self.modelForView.columnCount() - 1)
        itmCt = self.modelForView.data(id).toFloat()
```